# Why can't my tablet detect my bluetooth speaker after I reset the tablet?

Tags: wi-fi

I reset my galaxy tablet and it no longer detects my Sharkk Bluetooth speaker. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Could the speaker still be paired with the tablet before the reset? If so, it might not detect any new devices. You might need to reset the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your speaker into pairing-mode at first. You can get into it by holding the "M"-button for five seconds. After that, it should show up as a bluetooth-device on your tablet. I think, this video could also help: [Review Sharkk Portable Bluetooth Speaker](https://youtu.be/O3tNqk0Z-uM?t=2m28s)